# Variables do not work ? / in_array

Tags: php, html

I have two variables that don´t want to interact with `in_array`, I´m breaking my head on them.

**(First Part) Addition to Maincode:**

```
//Get Countrys
$Countrys = str_get_html($Disthtml);
$Countrys2 = $Countrys->find('span[class=regions regionsInt]');

//Get Departure Country
$DepartureC = $Countrys2[0];
$DepartureC2 = explode(',', $DepartureC);
$DepartureC3 = end($DepartureC2);
$DepartureC4 = str_replace(' ', '', $DepartureC3);
$DepartureCountry = $DepartureC4;

//Get Arrival Country
$ArrivalC = $Countrys2[1];
$ArrivalC2 = explode(',', $ArrivalC);
$ArrivalC3 = end($ArrivalC2);
$ArrivalC4 = str_replace(' ', '', $ArrivalC3);
$ArrivalCountry = $ArrivalC4;
```

**(Second Part) Maincode:**

```
//Check if Departure Country or Arrival Country is inside the EU
$CountrysEU = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'CzechRepublic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'UnitedKingdom');

if(in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU) || in_array($ArrivalCountry, $CountrysEU)){
    echo 'EU';
}
else {
    echo 'NotEU';
}
```

The variables `$ArrivalCountry` and `$DepartureCountry` are scraped (curl php) from a webpage and manipulated so they should fit the EU Countries by names if they are in the EU.

`Var_dump` of the two var:

```
$ArrivalCountry: string(13) "Russia" 
$DepartureCountry: string(20) "UnitedKingdom"
```

> Why doesn´t `in_array` work with my variables, it just outputs `NotEU`.

**Note:**

If I define the variables manually like this:

```
$ArrivalCountry = 'Russia'; 
$DepartureCountry = 'UnitedKingdom';
```

The code works perfectly.

Comment: Looks encoding problem, your characters in strings looks to be more than 1 byte.

Comment: @Muhammad  yes it's encoding problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running your code i got to know that your both countries have `</span>` in it and due to encoding problem they are not showing and confusing you.

You have to use below code to make it work:-

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); // add this encoding
include('simple_html_dom.php'); // i think you already have this

 // Your CURL CODE
 $Disthtml = curl_exec($ch2); // get Data from curl


$Countrys = str_get_html($Disthtml);

$Countrys = $Countrys->find('span[class=regions regionsInt]');

//Get Departure Country
$DepartureCountry = str_replace('</span>','',trim(end(explode(',', $Countrys[0])))); // remove unnecessary variable creation

//Get Arrival Country
$ArrivalCountry = str_replace('</span>','',trim(end(explode(',', $Countrys[1])))); // remove unnecessary variable creation


$CountrysEU = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'CzechRepublic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom');

if(in_array($ArrivalCountry, $CountrysEU) || in_array($DepartureCountry, $CountrysEU)){
    echo 'EU';
}
else {
    echo 'NotEU';
}
```